# How do I insert my credentials into the Client when using the ExactTarget S6 WSDL

Tags: marketing-cloud, c#, wsdl

I have imported the S6 WSDL into Visual Studio 2013 to generate the client code however I cannot figure out how to give it the clientSecret, clientId and/or auth token so that it can actually perform requests. Probably as a result, I always get the exception:

> SearchCustomer threw exception: 
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException: Security requirements are not satisfied because the security header is not present in the incoming message.

The code producing this exception is:

```
RetrieveRequest rq = new RetrieveRequest
{
    ObjectType = "MyObjectType",
    Properties = new[] {"EmailAddress"},
    Filter = new SimpleFilterPart
    {
        Property = "EmailAddress",
        SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.@equals,
        Value = new[] {"example@test.com"}
    }
};

using (PartnerAPI api = new PartnerAPI())
{
     string requestid;
     APIObject [] resultObjects;
     String result = api.Retrieve(rq, out requestid, out resultObjects);
}
```

(and the exception is occurring on `Retrieve`). How do I add credentials into the `RetrieveRequest` and/or the `PartnerAPI` so that this request is successful?

The WSDL I'm using is:
https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl

I also need this to work with just .NET 2, which means it looks like I can only add a "Web Reference" and not a "Service Reference".

Comment: Can you please confirm with API you are working with? Is it the ExactTarget/MarketingCloud API or the Partner API? They have different purposes and different ways of authenticating.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Given the WSDL I specified, can't it only be ExactTarget? Or have I misunderstood something? I am fairly sure it's salesforce marketing that is relevant here.

Comment: Just making certain we are talking about Marketing Cloud. There are instructions in [Connecting to the SOAP API using WCF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/connecting_to_the_web_service_api_using_wcf.htm) around how to set the required SOAP headers for authentication. You will need either an [Access Token or UsernameToken header](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/authenticate-soap-api.htm).

Comment: @DanielBallinger Thanks, we are definitely talking about marketing cloud. I forgot to mention that I need to use .NET 2 here, is it still possible to do this or do I have to just use rudimentary SOAP requests? When I add the WSDL through web reference I don't get the `SoapClient` class. It also looks like I am not able to add a "Service Reference" to a .NET 2 assembly. I will update my question, apologies for the lack of clarity.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Given these requirements, if I can't use the usual SOAP API, do you have any recommendation on what I should use?

Comment: If you are using .NET 2.0 they you will want the instructions from [Connecting to the SOAP API Using WSE 3.0 and .NET 2.0](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/connecting_to_the_web_service_api_using_wse_30_and_net_20.htm). You need to add WSE as a SOAP extension so you can add the required authentication headers. Failing that, I'd try and get the raw SOAP request going with SOAP UI. Then you can modify the C# code to replicate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89702/discussion-between-patrick-and-daniel-ballinger).